# Visual C# - Where to store processing files & do work instead of C:\ProgramFiles?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am fairly new to programming, I do not know all the best practices, so here I am asking what the best practice is when it comes the location of file processing.

I have created a Winforms program that does video trimming/conversion. My program currently installs to a user's C:\ProgramFiles(x86) Directory and I put all the necessary files required for the video processing in there. Unfortunately, in order to access those files at runtime and move them it requires elevated UAC. I currently have my program set to run as an administrator, but I no longer want to require my program to have to run as an administrator.

So what is best practice, where should I put these files during install, how can I access them without running the program as an administrator?

Ps: The reason I no longer want my program to run as an administrator is that It makes it extremly difficult allow drag & drop files onto a windows form.

Comment: I think the best practice would be to separate the working directory(files which are modified constantly ) with the rest of your application. This will also prevent UAC prompts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)` (e.g. C:\ProgramData\) Good place to store data that is shared across all users of the software. All users will have access to the data, so keep this in mind for privacy.

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` (e.g. C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\) Good place to store data that does not need to be synchronized if the user logs into the network from another computer. For example, storing debugging logs here makes sense.

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` (e.g. C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\). Good place to store data that needs to be synchronized if the user logs into the network from another computer. For example, storing an ini file here makes sense, as the user would want to have the same settings as before.

`Path.GetTempPath()` (e.g. C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp) Good place to store files that do not need to exist after the software is closed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I especially appreciate the code to locate those paths at run-time :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx), you will want to base your path on one of those, perhaps ApplicationData or LocalApplicationData.  Generally, you create a subdirectory in one of those with a company, product or program name and subdirectories in that for data, config, logs, etc.  Given, that video can be quite large you will want to provide your users with a way to set the path for data (for examples users may want to use a different drive, like an ssd).  So provide a default from the SpecialFolder enum, but allow users to override it with a user provided/selected path.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is to keep your application binaries and files that won't change in `%ProgramFiles%` but put files that are modified in `%AppData%`. This doesn't require administrator rights and you usually don't want those files to be the same for every user so that makes it convenient. You might also want to use either `Local` or `Roaming` depending on what kind of files you're storing but going with `Roaming` seems to be the most common thing for software.

One other way to do it (at least that's what I do with some programs that weren't done well) is to go in the software directory properties and give normal users the right to write there. However, I'm not sure how to do it within an installer and I don't consider this good practice (more a workaround when you're using old software).